# What is meant by 'House Keeping' in context of a database?

Tags: sql-server, database

One of my clients has mentioned the term 'Database House Keeping' in his tender specs. I am not sure about the term, please help.

Comment: to be exact its 'Data Archival & House Keeping'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

- Index rebuild or reorgansise
- Statistics update
- DBCC CHECKDB (check integrity etc)
  -etc

Other stuff:

- Check backups on tape/offline
- Check backups can be restored
- Monitor size changes
- etc

In this context, I guess:

- Managing older data (I've worked with systems with defined archive processes)

The 1st and 2nd list should be done anyway, regardless of what some vendor says.

Answer (score 4):

Probably he means clean-up of old records, either moving them to some kind of archive, or just deleting them.

But to be sure, you should ask him to clarify what he means.

Answer (score 2):

Usually things like:

1. Recalculating table statistics
2. Defragmenting tables and indexes
3. Backups
4. Managing data and file sizes

Answer (score 1):

I would assume it means maintaining the db, and cleaning up after yourself.  For instance, linking the tables properly so that if a user deletes their account, it automatically (or via a cron job/automatic process) cleans up the relational tables associated with that user.